# GOLANG случайное изображение

Tags: golang, случайные-числа

Всем привет. Допустим есть папка 1 в ней всегда разное количество изображений в формате *.jpg . Как сделать случайный выбор файла.

Comment: Список файлов + случайное число, представляющее индекс.

Comment: Можно код примерный?

Comment: Нет, делать все за вас никто не будет. Если есть конкретный вопрос - спрашивайте. Список сущностей в директории - http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir , случайное число - https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Intn

Comment: я логику как это сделать понял. есть у нас случайное число, есть список файлов. И что дальше?

Comment: Дальше выбираете файл из списка с индексом соответствующим числу.

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода, который выводит имя случайного файла

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
    "io/ioutil"
)
func main() {
    // Получаем список файлов (структура элемента https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo)
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(".")

    // Инициализируем генератор случайных чисел номером текущей наносекунды
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())

    // Выводим имя файла, выбранного случайно от нуля до количества файлов в списке
    fmt.Println(files[rand.Intn(len(files))].Name()) 
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PWzYGpYv0m

П.С.: В play.golang.org генератор случайных чисел всегда инициализируется одним и тем же числом, поэтому будет генерить одно и то же число.